# Test cases failing for OrientDB on powerpc

Tags: orientdb

I am officially porting OrientDB (community release) on powerpc ( ppc64le ) . I have cloned the repo from [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6210) and followed build steps as below :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb
$ git checkout develop
$ cd orientdb
$ mvn clean install
```

However getting test case failures as below

```
Failed tests: 
  TestBatchRemoteResultSet.runBatchQuery:59
Tests in error: 
  OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertexTest.testDeleteVertexBatch:87 » ODatabase Datab...
  OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertexTest.testDeleteVertexFromSubquery:114 » ODatabase
  OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertexTest.testDeleteVertexFromSubquery2:127 » ODatabase
  OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertexTest.testDeleteVertexLimit:72 » ODatabase Datab...
  SimplePropertyLinkTest.testSimplePropertyLink:27 ClassCast java.lang.String in...

Tests run: 384, Failures: 1, Errors: 5, Skipped: 123

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] OrientDB ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.305 s]
[INFO] OrientDB Test Commons .............................. SUCCESS [  5.100 s]
[INFO] OrientDB Core ...................................... SUCCESS [03:11 min]
[INFO] OrientDB Client .................................... SUCCESS [  7.290 s]
[INFO] OrientDB Object .................................... SUCCESS [ 15.109 s]
[INFO] OrientDB Tools ..................................... SUCCESS [  9.159 s]
[INFO] OrientDB Server .................................... SUCCESS [ 39.269 s]
[INFO] OrientDB GraphDB ................................... FAILURE [01:11 min]
[INFO] OrientDB Tests ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB Distributed Server ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB Lucene full text index .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB JDBC Driver ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB ETL ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB Community Distribution .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-15T13:25:21+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 134M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project orientdb-graphdb: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /root/amit/rethinkDB/orientDB_dev/graphdb/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :orientdb-graphdb


  [1]: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb
```

Any pointers on this , have raised a git issue ticket [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6210) , but thought of asking here if anyone has seen such errors.

Comment: It's not a question.

Comment: I understand its not a questions , seems more like a bug/issue for testing orientDB on powerpc , any comments on testing for power pc ?